# JPA: How to handle versioned entities?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, or-mapper

I have a versioning on an entity as part of its primary key. The versioning is done via a timestamp of the last modification:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class User {
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED", nullable = false)
  private LocalDateTime lastModified;

  // Constructors, Getters, Setters, ...

}

/**
 * This class is needed for using the composite key.
 */
public class CompositeKey {
  private UUID id;
  private LocalDateTime lastModified;
}
```

The `UUID` is translated automatically into a `String` for the database and back for the model. The same goes for the `LocalDateTime`. It gets automatically translated to a `Timestamp` and back.

A key requirement of my application is: **The data may never update or be deleted, therefore any update will result in a new entry with a younger `lastModified`.** This requirement is satisfied with  the above code and works fine until this point.

Now comes the problematic part: I want another object to reference on a User. Due to versioning, that would include the `lastModified` field, because it is part of the primary key. This yields a problem, because the reference might obsolete pretty fast.

A way to go might be depending on the `id` of the `User`. But if I try this, JPA tells me, that I like to access a field, which is not an `Entity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetail {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  private UUID userId;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean married;

  // Constructors, Getter, Setter, ...

}
```

**What would be the proper way of solving my dilemma?**

**Edit**

I got a suggestion by [JimmyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015327/jimmyb) which I tried and failed too. I added the failing code here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetail {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  private List<User> users;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean married;

  public User getUser() {
    return users.stream().reduce((a, b) -> {
      if (a.getLastModified().isAfter(b.getLastModified())) {
        return a;
      }
      return b;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("User detail is detached from a User."));
  }

  // Constructors, Getter, Setter, ...

}
```

Comment: "But if I try this, JPA tells me, that I like to access a field, which is not an Entity." - How/what did you try here?

Comment: To depend on the `id` of the `User`. I updated my question with a code sample.

Comment: Why the f... do you include the version in the primary key ????

Comment: As I stated in the requirement: The data may never change, therefore only inserts are allowed.

Comment: @Gab Because else he'd need to add another, artificial key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution, that is not really satisfying, but works. I created a `UUID` field `userId`, which is not bound to an `Entity` and made sure, it is set only in the constructor.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetail {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  // no setter for this field
  private UUID userId;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean married;

  public UserDetail(User user, boolean isMarried) {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    this.userId = user.getId();
    this.married = isMarried;
  }

  // Constructors, Getters, Setters, ...

}
```

I dislike the fact, that I cannot rely on the database, to synchronize the `userId`, but as long as I stick to the no setter policy, it should work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a logical 1:1 relationship which, due to versioning, becomes a technical 1:n relationship.

You have basically three options:

1. Clean JPA way: Declare an 'inverse' `@ManyToOne` relationship from user to the "other object" and make sure you always handle it whenever a new `User` record is created.
2. 'Hack-ish' way: Declare a `@OneToMany` relationship in the "other object" and force it to use a specific set of columns for the join using `@JoinColumn`. The problem with this is that JPA always expects unique reference over the join columns so that *reading* the `UserDetail` plus referenced `User` records should work, whereas *writing* `UserDetail` should *not* cascade onto `User` to avoid unwanted/undocumented effects.
3. Just store the user's `UUID` in the "other object" and resolve the reference yourself whenever you need it.

The added code in your question is wrong:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private UUID userId;
```

More correct, albeit not with the result you want, would be

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private User user;
```

This won't work though, because, as I said above, you may have more than one user record per `UserDetail`, so you'd need a `@OneToMany` relationship here, represented by a `Collection<User>`.

---

Another 'clean' solution is to introduce an artificial entity with a 1:1 cardinality w.r.t. to the logical `User` to which you can refer, like

```
@Entity
public class UserId {
  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="userId")
  private List<User> users;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="userId")
  private UserDetail detail;
}

@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private Long _id;

  @ManyToOne
  private UserId userId;

}

@Entity
public class UserDetail {

  @OneToOne
  private UserId userId;

}
```

This way, you can somewhat easily navigate from users to details and back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your second solution and failed (see updated answer). Could you please review it and point out any flaws you can find?

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to require seems to be on the lines of a history table, to keep track of the changes. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History on how EclipseLink can handle this for you while using normal/traditional JPA mappings and usage.

Comment: Hibernate calls the feature ["Envers"](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).

Comment: Thank you for this solution, unfortunately this violates the never update policy (by setting `end_date`, when the entry outdates). Otherwise, this would really the solution to my problem.

Comment: The end date makes it easier to query and tell when an item has been removed (soft delete), something I'm not sure how you would handle if the row cannot be modified.  The HistoryPolicy can be subclassed to get the functionality closer to what you want.